# Create many instance of a class

Tags: python, class, instance

I did create a class.

```
class Type:
    p = []
    r = []
    s = []
```

Then, in the main I use it 3 times.  The first one :

```
Short = Type()
```

then I use the list to append some data in it.
The second time I declare it

```
Avreage = Type()
```

But..  at that moment, evrey data that is in Short jump into Average.  Like if when a right Short.`p[0] = 2`, it write it in the class itself..  What do I have to do to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> class Type:
...     p = []
...     r = []
...     s = []
...
```

Here variable 'p', `r` and `s` are **class variable**.

**Class Variable Definition**: Variables declared inside the class definition, but not inside a method are class or static variables, which can me access by class instance i.e. object or by class name (outside of class).

e.g.

```
>>> a = Type()
>>> a.p
[]
>>> a.p.append(3)
>>> a.p
[3]
>>> b = Type()
>>> b.p
[3]
>>> Type.p
[3]
>>>
```